# Do we have to use for with label?

Tags: html

Which is the the better syntax for the use of label in HTML?

```
<label>Name:<br />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br /></label>
```

or

```
<label for="name">Name:<br /></label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Labels can wrap an input or reference them with the `for` attribute.  Both are semantically correct.

> A  can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the for attribute. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element. One input can be associated with multiple labels.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Nope.  They are the same thing.  This tag is used as a caption for user interface elements so its only purpose is to reference the element its it the caption of which can be done with the for attribute or by containing the input.

Answer (score 0):

Recording to w3schools **both** is correct

> The for attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Example from w3schools:

```
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <!-- label for male radio button -->      
      <label for="male">Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>

      <!-- label for female radio button -->      
      <label for="female">Female</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**Note:** This is especially useful for use with checkboxes and buttons, since it means you can check the box by clicking on the associated text instead of having to hit the box itself. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: You're linking to the page for the for attribute. Obviously, that page is only going to tell you the correct syntax for the for attribute, ignoring the equally valid other option.

Comment: Is w3schools the most important entity to trust ? Because here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label they give the both syntax as examples.

Comment: Not at all. We're all better off pretending W3Schools doesn't exist.

Comment: w3schools referes to the website of the website of the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C. "W3" is a common abbreviation for the World Wide Web, and just because a company has "W3" in its name doesn't mean it is associated with the W3C in any way. (And this is one reason why we're better off pretending W3Schools doesn't exist.)